# Autodesk Forge how to save and show Markups

Tags: autodesk-forge, forge

[response data for svg markups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NieKp.png)

[markups in model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ObpY.png)

I want to save all svg Markups on model and show them.
I try to save Markups with this code
    ```` ```markupsPersist = markup.generateData();
    viewerStatePersist = markup.viewer.getState();
    markup.viewer.restoreState(viewerStatePersist);```
and try to get it with this ````
    `markup.viewer.restoreState(viewerStatePersist);
    markup.show();
    markup.loadMarkups(markupsPersist, "markups-svg");`
but Markups dont appear.

Comment: Your code looks alright - can you share the model file as well as the svg data so I can try and reproduce the issue (upload to GDrive/Dropbox etc and drop the link to forge.help@autodesk.com)? Does it work if you only save and load one or two of your markups? What was printed to the console when you loaded the markups?

Comment: Thank you for your response, but i can only send you screenshoots, because i dont have a permission to share project  files.

Comment: i am edited my question and add screenshots of model with markups and response data for svg markups

Comment: Not sure if the SVG string is correct (or maybe I got it wrong somewhere when extracting the text) - see live demo [here](https://jsbin.com/watelot) (code [here](https://jsbin.com/watelot/edit?js )) , it'd throw an error loading the markups after the model's loaded... you can clone this demo to reproduce your issue in a live environment

Comment: I think you are right.Probably the svg is not correct, but what can i do in this case, do you have any decision?

Comment: Thank you for your help and support, but problem  was in my code, svg is correct and work.

Answer (score 0):

You should also call `showMarkups` after loading them using `loadMarkups`.